# Idea for protecting hashed passwords

Tags: cryptography, passwords

Since breaking password hashes has become a new passtime for scriptkiddies, I thought of the problem and came up with a novel(?) idea.

1. store the pass as offset+number instead of hash
2. the number is a product of two large primes
3. the password is converted into a number , offset is added and that prime is used to divide the number. If it divides AND the divisor is the larger of the two primes the password is correct.

by definition , each hash is unique and each password can be hashed in many different ways depending on the offset. Breaking one hash means you have to factor the number(which is hard), then find a word which corresponds to a number that is largerprime-offset (which is trivial).

To generate use function f() to turn password into a password-number (not important) , generate two random primes larger than 2^4096 or however much is enough. Take the larger prime and calculate prime-passwordnumber=offset. Multiply the primes to get "number". store number and offset.

To check. use function f() to turn password into a password-number, add offset to find prime. divide number with prime to get the other prime. Check that the first prime was the bigger of the two. If so, password was correct.

f() might be for example utf-8 encoding of the password understood as a large binary integer.

Comment: You'll get better answers in [cryptography](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: well. I will post this here if I get nothing here.

Comment: This is missing a lot of details.  Can you write pseudocode for generating and validating the hashes?

Comment: @MarkusMikkolainen An advice: don't use comments like forum posts. Information relevant to the question should be put in the question itself editing it. Stackoverflow works differently than a forum.

Comment: I really don't see how this should work. I agree, this should be posted on crypto, if possible using a mathematical description of the protocol. Pseudocode would be more useful on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Your procedure doesn't really gain you anything over using a hash function. Reversing your function is difficult, yes, since it requires factoring large numbers, but reversing regular hash functions is also difficult. An attacker can still employ the same procedure they would against a regular hash algorithm: employ a brute force attack by testing every possible password.

This, of course, is inevitable with any scheme that stores sufficient data to validate the password. The only solution is to make it computationally expensive for the attacker to do so, by making the hash function expensive to compute, and by adding a salt to make sure they can't precompute.

Comment: Yes, this is as easy to brute for simple passwords as hashes , except i dont think you can practically rainbow this one. Also It supports basically any length in a password without collision. In essence you can add difficulty by adding a random prefix to the password and not store it, then do the trial divisions by yourself. This will add a constant work factor.

Comment: No, you can't use a rainbow table, because this is the equivalent of a salted hash, which you _also_ can't use a rainbow table for. And the output length being proportional to the password length is a weakness, not a strength - it allows an attacker to learn information about the password.

Comment: I dont think it will actually give the attacker any information. The output length wont change with the password length unless the password is insanely large so that you have to make the primes larger, and in that case you cant really know if the primes are large for security or for the password.

Comment: So to summarize, your solution is no harder to break than a salted hash, and might be easier. What's the advantage?

Comment: Well since this is quite basic math, i think it is possible to prove that this is secure from non-brute attacks, while hashes seem to be broken all the time.

Answer (score 0):

In general, trying to invent your own crypto system is *very* hard to do correctly. There are many little things that you have to consider, and it's easy to miss something that an attack can exploit. You'd still be much better off and safer if you used an established cryptography or hashing library. Bcrypt for hashing will probably be much more secure than the solution you posted.

Comment: yes, I know that and I use known hashing techniques. This just popped into my mind this morning on the train station while waiting for a train and I cant see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: That's all fine and dandy, but please see it as a learning experience. This is probably not the best scheme around - *if* it works at all (can't tell without a better definition).

Answer (score 0):

To formalize your scheme:

To create the hash:

1. User enters password pw
2. Convert pw to a byte array ba with an encoding function e
3. Convert ba to a large integer bn
4. Find prime numbers p and q, p > q > max(bn, 2^2048)
5. Store n = pq and o = p - bn

To verify the hash:

1. User enters password pw
2. Convert pw to a byte array ba with an encoding function e
3. Convert ba to a large integer bn
4. Verify that bn + o divides n

This being a secure hash requires that given n and o, it's not feasible to deduce pw, i.e. there is no algorithm that gives an advantage over guessing and checking.  I believe it.

As I see it, the main benefit of your scheme is the randomness injected into the hashing process by selecting the random numbers.  That they are primes and factoring should be hard is more of an implementation detail (it's your one-way function).  Presumably it should also slow down checks, though I really don't know how slow division is on numbers that large.

It is interesting that the hash creation and password verification processes are so different.  As you point out, this makes the technique of rainbow table hash chaining inapplicable.  This may be something of an advantage, but per-user salting gets you similar protection from rainbow tables.

Comment: One advantage is that there is really no upper size on the password. In a normal hash , once you gather the 128 bits of entropy for a 128bit hash, you start getting collisions. In this case you can just take a longer password and increase the bit size of the primes if needed.

Comment: Other advantage (I think) is that this can't be rainbow tabled, so bruting is really bruting.

Comment: I don't think it's any more resilient to rainbow tables than SHA256 with an equivalent (4096 bit) salt.  The only difference is that the entropy is built into your design and so is not optional.

Comment: The idea with rainbow tables is that you can chain hashes. How do you chain these?

Comment: Yes, that's interesting.  I'll need to think about it some more and update my answer.

Comment: @MarkusMikkolainen Sorry, but hash collisions are not really a problem, certainly not regarding passwords. This indicates you are probably not the right person to create a new password hashing scheme (don't worry, neither am I at the time of writing).